# Adding multiple users at once to PFRelation IOS objective c

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, cloud, pfuser, pfrelation

Im wanting to add multiple users that I queried to a PFRelation all at once. How do I go about doing this. Also will all of the users information be stored in the PFRelation so that the current user can access it at a later time?

```
//so now i am finding users in the PFRelation, but I cannot use the Users information in a table. The code for the table view is at the bottom. 
PFQuery * query =[self.matchesRelation query];
    [query orderByDescending:@"Score"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            self.myMatches =[objects mutableCopy];
            [self.tableView reloadData];




        }

    }];




//code for the tableview, i can set the users username fine but anything else i cant

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString * CellIdentifier =@"Cell";
    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.person =[self.myMatches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




    cell.name.text = self.person.username;
   //this does not work, why ? 
   cell.score.text =[self.person objectForKey:@"Score"];


    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the items in your `self.myMatches` array, adding each one to the `myMatches` relation.

Once you are done simply save the parent object that contains the relation, which in your case is `[PFUser currentUser]`.

Comment: what do you mean loop through ? For in loop or just a standard for loop?

Comment: Okay so the users have been saved successfully to parse but, when i try to get any of the the users info apart from the user name and objectId and display it in a table view it dosnt work. I will post the code above.

Comment: Its okay i found the error. The error was due to that i was passing in a NSNumber to an NSString value :P